# Excel Increment cell reference upon success

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I unfortunately do not have access to create a macro, so I have to do the coding by use of formulas. My question is if it is possible to increment cell value if a success has happened.

```
IF(A1=B1,'Sheet1'!A1,equal)
```

So what I want is some function for 'Sheet1'!A1, to make it only increment when it is used. So when I pull the formula A1=B1, will change in every cell. But 'Sheet1'!A1 will only increment to 'Sheet1'!A2, when 'Sheet1'!A1 is used. And from then on be 'Sheet1'!A2, until a new increment happens.

```
     B                     C                   D
```

[image]

As shown on the example on the above picture, in the middle row the following formula exists:

```
=IF(LEFT(D9,3)<>LEFT(D10,3),'2_System documentation'!D30,"See Above.")
```

so the true statement `'2_System documentation'!D30`, should only change if it is used. Is it possible without using macro?

**Another try at explanation**

I am sorry that the explanation was not good enough. This was the most descriptive. But I will try in another way here:

IF(A1 = B1, true, C1), lets say it is true for 10 times, then when I drag the formula down I still want this result: IF(A11 = B11, true, C1). Now A11 = B11 is not true therefore the result is C1, when I continue dragging the next formula should be IF(A12 = B12, true, C2). Such that C only increases if it has been used. Hope this was more precise?

**Code Try**

```
Struct Cell;

New savedCell = excel.sheet.cell(C1);


Cell Function(cell1,cell2)
{
    Cell Temp = null;
    If(cell1 == cell2)
    {
        Temp = new cell{True};
    }
    Else
    {
        Temp = savedCell;
        savedCell = excel.sheet.cell(C2)
    }
    return Temp;
}
```

Where the struct Cell corresponds to an excel cell.

savedCell, is the one that corresponds to the cell that should only increment upon success.

is this possible to do in a formula you pull down in fill in all cells. Or do I need a macro.

Comment: @pnuts, I am sorry that the explanation is not good enough. This was the best I could do. But I will try in another way here:
`IF(A1 = B1, true, C1)`, lets say it is true for 10 times, then when I drag the formula down I still want this result: `IF(A11 = B11, true, C1)`.
Now A11 = B11 is not true therefore the result is C1, when I continue dragging the next formula should be `IF(A12 = B12, true, C2)`. Such that C only increases if it has been used. Hope this was more precise?

Comment: @pnuts It is just where I pull the variables from different sheets. I can see now that that was bad infromation. but no when it is pulled down ten rows where everything is true it would be IF(A11 = B11, true, C1). But when it is not true C will be incremented i.e. IF(A12 = B12, true, C2). That is why it is not enough to use $C$1, because at some point it should increase.

Comment: Yeah, I think I have to come up wit ha better way to explain, I have included some pseudo code to try and explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this may not be easy to explain with my poor English but I will try.

First I am assuming you have 3 columns, A B and C. first 2 columns are the data you would like to compare and C column is the data you would like to see as result but you want to see following result when a spesific condition meet. I have created following table in the excel

[image]

In that table I used the D column to find the required row number for the C column with following formula starting from the second cell (D2):

```
=IF(A1=B1,D1,D1+1)
```

After that D column is the result you want with following formula:

```
=IF(A2=B2,TRUE,INDIRECT(F2))
```

and E column is the address of the C column with increasing condition, formula:

```
="C"&D2
```

I hope this solve your problem.

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to mention that first row is headers except column D. I put 1 there for the formula. You may need to keep that 1 in the first cell of column D.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intended use correctly, I think this should work without needing helper columns.

For the first entry, I'm assuming that A1=B1 and you want to pull the title from C1. The following assumes that the "target" column is D. For D1, just make it equal C1. For the rest of the column, you can enter this for the rest of the column:

```
=IF(A2=B2,D1,INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D1,C:C,0)+1))
```

Basically, column D is listing the titles. If in row n An=Bn,  Dn will list the same title as the cell above it, D(n-1). If An=/=Bn, Dn will pull the next title from column C.